# return tuple with two arrays

Tags: c#, tuples

I am trying to call a function which returns a tuple with two arrays. The content of the arrays are based on checked items in a checkedListBox.
I define the arrays and call the function "storeParametersInArrays" as shown below.

```cs
string[] allowedObjects = new string[checkedListObjects.CheckedItems.Count]; // All allowed objects
string[] notallowedObjects = new string[checkedListObjects.Items.Count - checkedListObjects.CheckedItems.Count]; // All not allowed objects

Tuple<string[], string[]> ObjParameters = storeParametersInArrays(notallowedObjects, allowedObjects, checkedListObjects);
allowedObjects = ObjParameters.Item1;
notallowedObjects = ObjParameters.Item2;
```

The function called is defined as:

```cs
private Tuple<string[], string[]> storeParametersInArrays(string[] notallowed, string[] allowed, CheckedListBox checkedListBox)
{
    int i = 0; // allowed objects
    int j = 0; // not allowed objects
    int k = 0; // item counter

    foreach (object item in checkedListBox.Items)
    {
        if (!checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Contains(item))
        {
            notallowed[j++] = checkedListBox.Items[k].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            allowed[i++] = checkedListBox.Items[k].ToString();
        }
        k++;
    }
    return Tuple.Create<allowed, notallowed>;
}
```

I am unable to return the Tuple in the above code sample. I get the error "Cannot convert method group 'Create' to non-delegate type 'Tuple'".

It is my first time working with tuples, how can I return the two arrays without having to call the function twice?

I have looked at slightly similar problems, so if the question is already answered somewhere else, I will be glad to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: `Tuple.Create` is a method. See this page for proper usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple.create?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Tuple_Create__2___0___1_

Comment: You placed the values where the type parameters should be. But I think that the type parameters can be inferred here: `return Tuple.Create(allowed, notallowed);`

Comment: You´re just missing brackets behing `Tuple.Create`.

Comment: Tuple.Create(a,b);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change

```
return Tuple.Create<allowed, notallowed>;
```

to

```
return Tuple.Create(allowed, notallowed);
```

The first syntax is for generics: `<`

The second for method calls: `(`

Comment: Thank you! That was easier than I thought :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to correct your method call `Tuple.Create`:

```
private Tuple<string[], string[]> storeParametersInArrays(string[] notallowed, string[] allowed, CheckedListBox checkedListBox)
{
    int i = 0; // allowed objects
    int j = 0; // not allowed objects
    int k = 0; // item counter

    foreach (object item in checkedListBox.Items)
    {
        if (!checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Contains(item))
        {
            notallowed[j++] = checkedListBox.Items[k].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            allowed[i++] = checkedListBox.Items[k].ToString();
        }
        k++;
    }
    return Tuple.Create(allowed, notallowed);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
return Tuple.Create<allowed, notallowed>;
```

replace with

```
return Tuple.Create<string[], string[]>(allowed, notallowed);
```

Or simple

```
return Tuple.Create(allowed, notallowed);
```

The static method Create is a generic method and the error is that you are using the values like the types that the Create method will return.

Answer (score 1):

You placed the values where the type parameters should be. But I think that the type parameters can be inferred here:

```
return Tuple.Create(allowed, notallowed);
```

However, you could use new [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.7.2)s. A simplified [tuple syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples?view=netframework-4.7.2) was introduced in C# 7.0.

```
private (string[], string[]) storeParametersInArrays(
    string[] notallowed, string[] allowed, CheckedListBox checkedListBox)
{
    ...
    return (allowed, notallowed);
}
```

You can then get the result stored directly into your existing variables with:

```
(allowedObjects, notallowedObjects) = storeParametersInArrays(
    notallowedObjects, allowedObjects, checkedListObjects);
```

---

But since arrays are reference types, you don't even have to return them from the method. You are not passing copies of the arrays to the method - only references. Therefore the method fills the original arrays.

```
private void storeParametersInArrays(
    string[] notallowed, string[] allowed, CheckedListBox checkedListBox)
{
    // Fill the arrays here.

    // No need for a return statement.
}
```

Now you can write

```
storeParametersInArrays(notallowedObjects, allowedObjects, checkedListObjects);

// allowedObjects and notallowedObjects are now filled. Example
string firstAllowed = allowedObjects[0];
```

---

You can even go a step further and use the [Local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) introduced in C# 7.0. They have access to the variables of the surrounding method and therefore don't require the parameters in this case.

```
void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] allowedObjects = new string[...];
    string[] notallowedObjects = new string[...];

    storeParametersInArrays();

    // Use the result
    string firstAllowed = allowedObjects[0];

    // Nested local function
    void storeParametersInArrays()
    {
        // You can access allowedObjects, notallowedObjects and checkedListObjects here.
        // Fill the arrays.
    }
}
```

Comment: That is simply amazing! Much easier to look at - thank you!